# Select first row but only if there's more than one match?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the table `users` below:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | name    | office |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | David   |      1 |
|  2 | Roz     |      1 |
|  3 | Patrick |      2 |
|  4 | Chris   |      3 |
|  5 | Agnes   |      3 |
|  6 | Freya   |      3 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

I want to select the first user of any given office, but ONLY if there's more than one user, so:

- Office 1 = User 1 (David)
- Office 2 = **NULL**
- Office 3 = User 4 (Chris)

Something along the lines of:

```
SET @office_id = 2;
SELECT *
  FROM `users`
WHERE `office` = @office_id AND number-of-users-for-office > 1
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.office, 
        MAX(
        CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL
            THEN NULL
            ELSE a.Name
        END) Name
FROM    Tablename a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  office, MIN(id) ID
            FROM    Tablename
            GROUP   BY office
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON  a.office = b.office AND
                a.ID = b.ID
-- WHERE .......                       -- (if you have extra conditions)
GROUP   BY a.office
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55473/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║ OFFICE ║  NAME  ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║      1 ║ David  ║
║      2 ║ (NULL) ║
║      3 ║ Chris  ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

The purpose of the subquery is to get the least ID for every `Office`. The extra `HAVING` clause filters only records that has more than one employee within the certain office.

Table `User` is then joined on the subquery via `LEFT JOIN` to get all the office within the table. The records are aggregated using `MAX()` (*or `MIN()`*) to get single record for every `office`.

Comment: Assuming I have indexes on the `office` column, what kind of performance difference do you think there would be between your query and @Shafeeq's below?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55473/15 - modified to retrieve a single office

Comment: @oodavid are columns `office` and `name` you like to fetch in your final result or the one you showed above is just like an example?

Comment: Yeah, just an example; the real problem is more complex so I've distilled it down into something simple for SO.

I'm actually writing a trigger to automatically link my `items` to the first AND last `item_records` table that reference an `item` to save on overhead.

We commonly want to know "when did we first make a record of this item" and "when did we last make a record of this item" but I don't want them to be the same, hence needing to check if there's more than one record of the item.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution that I'm jotting for posterity.

```
-- Office id...
SET @office_id = 1;
-- Find the latest user
SELECT `id` INTO @latest_user_id
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `office` = @office_id
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 1;
-- Find the first user that isn't the first
SELECT `id` INTO @latest_user_id
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `office` = @office_id AND `id` != @latest_user_id
    ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12c59/6)

This one selects the latest, then tries to select the first where it's not the same as the latest. Thus if there's only 1 row you'll get NULL as desired.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

```
SELECT `office`,if(count(`id`)>1,name,'NULL') as name
FROM (SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER BY id ASC)
`tablename`
GROUP BY `office`
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Comment: I find this technique easy to read / understand; I've modified the query to suit my requirement (just looking for a single office) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/746143/1

Comment: According to sql standard, the records returned from a subquery is unordered set of rows even if it contains `ORDER BY` clause in it. In your example, maybe it works since you only have few set of rows. But still I can't tell if this query will work on large tables where it contains millions of rows. A question was asked here [ORDER BY is being ignored..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481867/order-by-is-being-ignored-in-subquery-join)

Comment: @oodavid, I think you misunderstood. ORDER BY will unordered only when if you are using GROUP BY clause on same query. In my query, subquery not having the GROUP BY clause. I hope this will work on millions of rows. May be performance matters

Comment: @491243 your link backs up Shafeeq's statement about it not working as expected when combined with a GROUP BY. Which is true?